# PayPal REST API / paypal-checkout Javascript integration: setting payee, permission denied

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm having a problem using the REST API along with the
paypal-checkout javascript integration
(https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout) to set a third party as the
payment receiver.

According to this

https://devblog.paypal.com/setting-payee/

a third-party payee should be allowed now. Correct?

The heart of the matter seems to be this call:

```
paypal.rest.payment.create(button_member.env,
                           button_member.client,
                           pp_data_member);
```

where button_member.env is "sandbox"

and button_member.client is

```
{"sandbox":"Ab**********0O","production":"AW**********38"}
```

When pp_data_member is

```
{"intent":"authorize",
  "payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},
  "transactions":[
    { "amount":{"total":"5.50",
               "currency":"USD",
               "details":{
                 "subtotal":"5.00","tax":"0.00","shipping":"0.50"
               }},
      "payee":{"email":"development-facilitator@troc*****.com"},
      "soft_descriptor":"ZenKitsch",
      "notify_url":
          "https://www.trocadero.com/_internal/alpha/**********",
      "description":"Your Zen Kitsch order of September 16, 2017",
      "invoice_number":"CHKT-zenkitsch-479618-SV16M8PSFG",
      "item_list":{
        "items":[{"sku":"844697","name":"United Airlines Beverage Menu Card","quantity":"1","price":"5.00","currency":"USD"}]
     }
    }
  ]
}
```

all works fine. But when I set the payee to a different sandbox address and
nothing else changes:

```
...
      "payee":{"email":"development-seller@troc*****.com"},
...
```

while I get the popup as expected, after I log in with the buyer sandbox
account and confirm the purchase, I get a failure back from the API, a
400 status code and a "contingency":"PERMISSION_DENIED" error message:

```
Request URL: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/payment/PAY-9TX329794L770414LLG6YSZQ/execute
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:173.0.82.77:443


{"ack":"contingency",
  "contingency":"PERMISSION_DENIED",
  "meta":  
    {"calc":"e305762ccebe",       
     "rlog":"7Jz2DIxLg7B25ErQ1yIJI2shyI%2FIqDJZY2fbMMEef%2FVnBUNHVn2YYp4ptK5fN6DoGzjRHFjL6nRZkZqdnHIRwQ_15e8c60e8a8"
    },
  "server":"6ajNNYfBIhVmBs2ogHWhF35ezBlTaOHlCtx2erpwzk-5XmIY9isE5Hk07x5GBputw5DXmqsjLE71y3mJtJHw6TPBWcgBGzPpOkEXIWpJVOPsgsani23mTTQPfrrhKtd2pLLSFQDXQ0ISqpWOC0vZa4DvUshowfLFfFn_oNyAB_gquO5vWd1wIZOEp8z6EiUAnjsDBhCv1K1xBjn6KsOFyczIThuWeoh86RnPLJnhzpqXWAuSDCof_00kGVXCskQDxDqLpa4-0Ry"
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edited to add: small code to demo the issue. The first button with payee set to app owner works, the second button fails with an error that can be ssen in the console.

```
<html><head><title>PP Button Test</title></head>
<body>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" data-version-4></script>

<div id="myContainerElement1"></div>
<hr>
<div id="myContainerElement2"></div>
<script>
paypal.Button.render({
    client: {
        sandbox:    'AbR*****T0O', 
        production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
    },
    payment: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: {
                        total:    '1.00',
                        currency: 'USD'
                    },
                    payee:{email:'development-facilitator@troc*****.com'},
                }
            ]
        });
    },
    commit: true,
    locale: 'en_US',
    style: {
        size:   'medium', // tiny, small, medium
        color:  'blue', // orange, blue, silver
        shape:  'pill'    // pill, rect
    },
    env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' or 'production'
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function(response) {
            console.log('payment 1 completed!');
        });
    },
    onCancel: function(data) {
        console.log('payment 1 was cancelled!');
    }
}, '#myContainerElement1');


paypal.Button.render({
    client: {
       sandbox:    'AbRF38w5WaF4qE3nSr_JLsxdGGOEGSpS4wxI8HbW-QYcnISvpmPEc-hJfUemR1k57IrCKwBDNamV9T0O', 
        production: 'xxxxxxxxx'  
    },
    payment: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: {
                        total:    '1.00',
                        currency: 'USD'
                    },
                    payee:{email:'development-seller@troc*****.com'},
                }
            ]
        });
    },
    commit: true,
    locale: 'en_US',
    style: {
        size:   'medium', // tiny, small, medium
        color:  'blue', // orange, blue, silver
        shape:  'pill'    // pill, rect
    },
    env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' or 'production'
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute().then(function(response) {
            console.log('payment 2 completed!');
        });
    },
    onCancel: function(data) {
        console.log('payment 2 was cancelled!');
    }
}, '#myContainerElement2');


</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Is the payer using a credit card? Is payer using something other than PayPal wallet and payee does not have PayPal account?

Comment: Both payee and payer here are PayPal sandbox accounts. Payment is made with account balance.

Comment: Oh sorry I was just suggesting some obvious possibilities, like is power on/plugged in sort of thing. If problem persists maybe try rest api directly instead of the open source implementation, could be a bug, or not updated yet? Are last pulls before 3rd party added?

Comment: @TomSwiss I have exactly the same problem...do you have any news since the time of the question? Thanks